# Getting an alert box in JS without using alert()

Tags: web-application, xss, javascript

This is an `XSS` vulnerability I've found in a practice site. So, I need to create an `alert()` popup, but `alert()` is changed to `prompt()` by another script loaded before I give any input. (So I can't get rid of that script)
So how can I make an `alert()` popup?

The code strips `<`, `>`, and `+` (I've only found these three) but changing my payload and injecting them doesn't seem to help.

I've tried `window\["alert"](1)` which is also detected. So are `window["al"+"ert"]` and `window["al".concat("ert")]`.

I think I need to find another solution instead of alert(), but I have no clue where to proceed from here.

Comment: Normally being able to trigger a prompt would be sufficient to prove XSS - is this a specific challenge to trigger an alert, rather than a generic XSS challenge?

Comment: @Matthew, apparently yes. No prompt or confirm helps. (XSS is allowed deliberately, so that is not the point of the challenge in this case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with a fresh copy of `window`:

```
document
.body
.appendChild(document.createElement("iframe"))
.contentWindow
.alert("XSS");
```

you can cleanup/hide the iframe as needed, it doesn't have to navigate, it just has to exist to expose its global `window` methods. Think of it as a web worker with more built-ins. Note that even though chrome46+ block alerts *from* iframes, you're not calling it *from* the iframe technically, so it's allowed. This is also a decent way to avoid re-writes/fork to run a process that conflicts with pre-existing code which doesn't need the document's content to function, but needs DOM tools that `Worker` doesn't provide, like `alert`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I hadn't known about this though, need to read up a bit on it.